# HTML query string restrictions?

Tags: html, http

So, I have some additional data I want to provide with request.

For example:

```
/tests/46/add_key?keyword=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&position=22
```

But beside this, I want to pass **color** query, like this:

```
 /tests/46/add_key?keyword=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&position=22&color=#68d574
```

But this way final request is:

```
Started POST "/tests/46/add_key?keyword=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE&position=200&color="
```

As I change query to string only with `[a-zA-Z]`, like `'red'`:

```
Started POST "/tests/46/add_key?keyword=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE&position=200&color=red"
```

The request is what I expect.

So, the query which doesn't go to server (`#68d574`) contains symbol, I can't use in requests (`#`). Or what?

Can you explain please

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` character indicates the start of the [fragment identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), so it terminates the query string. Since the fragment id is only used client side, it isn't even sent to the server.

As with any character which has special meaning in a URI, you can include it as data by [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) it (in this particular case as `%23`).

Comment: Thanks! And where I find out, how to encode other symbols I may need?

Comment: I liked to the URL specification in the answer, that will tell you.